# ListPlot filling not appearing when point is out of range

Tags: plotting

In a non-joined `ListPlot` one can specify that a filling line is shown for each point:

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}], Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Red]
```

[image: 1]

But if the points are out of the plot range, the filling line no longer appears:

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}], Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}]
```

[image: 2]

Is there any way to still show the line up the plot range, to show that there is a point there (but you just can't see it)?  Or must I draw the lines myself with a `Prolog`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One solution is to use `ListPlot` with `PlotRange->All` (in your example you don't need it) and crop the region afterwards by calling `Show`:

```
gr = ListPlot[Table[{x, Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}], Filling -> Axis,
    FillingStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All];
Show[gr, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 0.4}}]
(* or shorter Show[gr, PlotRange -> {0, 0.4}] *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Since only the $y$-range is being changed, one could also do the shorter `Show[gr, PlotRange -> {0, 0.4}]`.

Comment: @J.M. added to the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the option `ClippingStyle -> False` gives the desired result:

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}], 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.4}, 
 ClippingStyle -> False]
```

[image]

**See:** [this answer by Coolwater](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41708/125)