# Unwanted PlotMarkers appear at non-existent places

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

---

In this simple code

```
ListPlot[Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi, .1}], PlotRange -> {0, 0.5},
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

We can see that there are two PlotMarkers appear at the clipped boundary. But actually there are not points, so they should not exist. How can we remove them? I have already used `ClippingStyle -> None`.

---

**Update**

As Alexey Popkov pointed out, this is really a bug. If we play with this code

```
data = {Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 1.05 Pi, .1}], Table[{x, Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 1.05 Pi, .1}]};
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}]
```

[image]

Now, even the same plot marker will be used for all data sets at the clipped boundaries, both top and bottom.

Comment: I think this behavior should be considered as a bug: the combination of `Joined -> True` with `PlotMarkers -> Automatic` and default values for `ClippingStyle` and `PlotRangePadding` produces spurious plot markers at the edges of plot. Here is better example: `ListPlot[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 1.05 Pi, .1}], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]`.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov, I agree, already reported.

Comment: This bug is still present in version 10.0.0.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi, .1}], PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}, Joined ->
True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> False, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: I just guessed this

Comment: @Coolwater, good guess, thanks! `None` vs `False`, I remember there are similar cases, but can't exactly recall them for now.

Comment: PlotRangePadding -> None works too. It's documented, but not on the list of options in ListPlot-documentation, so you need to evaluate "ListPlot//Options" to find it

Comment: FYI: `ClippingStyle -> None` does *not* work in v7, but `False` does.

Comment: X is varied from 0 to Pi i.e 3.14 but in the plot 30.4, why it is so can anybody tell me?

Comment: @Udichi When the first argument of `ListPlot` is a list of numbers, the numbers are considered to be 2nd coordinates and the first coordinates are assumed to be `Range[Length[listOfNumbers]]`

Comment: Thanks @Coolwater. Adding "ClippingStyle -> False" will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be fixed in 12.1.1 (at the latest):

[image: screenshot of notebook]