# ListPlot inserts extra PlotMarkers and Mesh at crossing points

Tags: graphics, plotting

In the example below, `ListPlot` with `PlotMarkers -> Automatic` and a variant using `Mesh -> All` introduces extra points at crossing points, even with `InterpolationOrder->None`.

Is there a way to prevent these?

```
With[{dates = {1906, 1907, 1912, 1929, 1941, 1949, 1952, 1953, 1965, 
    1976, 1998, 1998}, evens = Range[0, 11]*(92/11) + 1906  }, 
 ListPlot[{dates, evens}, Joined -> True,
  InterpolationOrder -> None, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Closely related: [(41706)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41706/121) I imagine that the cause is the same.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't know if they're precisely the same bug, but definitely related, and fixed in current sources, i.e. it will be in a future release.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for the note! Nice to see you around. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm here almost everyday, whether I participate or not depends on the day. For a while there, I had the longest streak at well over a year. I believe (without evidence, of course) that my number of days present is among the top on the site.

Answer (score 8):

Using the setting `Mesh->Full` seems to solve the issue (in both Version 9 and 10):

```
With[{dates = {1906, 1907, 1912, 1929, 1941, 1949, 1952, 1953, 1965, 
    1976, 1998, 1998}, evens = Range[0, 11]*(92/11) + 1906},
 ListPlot[{dates, evens}, Joined -> True,
  Mesh -> Full, InterpolationOrder -> None,
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, ImageSize -> 400]]
```

[image]

[Mesh > Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mesh.html) :

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

I assume the extra points are created for the filling polygon, and erroneously given a plot marker along with the "real" points. A simple workaround is just to create two plots, one with filling and one with plot markers, and combine them with `Show`:

```
With[{dates = {1906, 1907, 1912, 1929, 1941, 1949, 1952, 1953, 1965, 
    1976, 1998, 1998}, evens = Range[0, 11]*(92/11) + 1906},
 Show[
  ListPlot[{dates, evens}, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> None, #] & /@ 
   {PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}}]]
```

[image]