# ListLinePlot continuation marker

Tags: plotting

I'm probably not going to use the correct terminology, but I'm trying to find out how to suppress the markers that Mathematica puts on plot lines that go outside the bottom of the frame.[image]

Comment: How did you generate this plot? Please post the code.

Comment: This seems to be a known and persistent bug, tracing all the way back to version 7: [Unwanted PlotMarkers appear at non-existent places](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41706/27951). Adding `ClippingStyle -> False` should act as a workaround.

Comment: Probably related as well: [ListPlot inserts extra PlotMarkers and Mesh at crossing points](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63567/27951).

Comment: @Felix You can reproduce the behavior with `ListLinePlot[Table[{x, -n x}, {n, 2}, {x, 0, 3}], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotRange -> -5]`.

Comment: Thank you, MarcoB.  That solved my problem!