# Bug in ListPlot: Duplicate markers (one list containing ``Infinity``)

Tags: plotting, bugs

simple plot of two lists, of which one contains infinity (markers are slightly shifted):

```
ListPlot[
    {{3, 4, 5},{1, Infinity, 2}},
    PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledDiamond]", 13}, {"   \[FilledDiamond]", 13}},
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}
]
```

What I get is this:

[image]

**Note the duplicate red points for each black point!**

This definitely doesn't seem right, can someone confirm that?

My current workaround is to just replace all `Infinity`s with a low number and then adjust the `PlotRange`.

**Update**: I contacted the Mathematica Technical Support Team, which confirmed the bug and said they'd work on that.
In the meantime, there's plenty of workarounds, so I marked the question as solved.

Cheers

Comment: For others seeing this question: Usually, we have the rule to only apply the `[bugs]` tag to *confirmed* bugs, but I believe the situation is pretty clear and the example is simple enough to assume that what happens here is not OK. @kuropan, Would you consider reporting this to Wolfram, so that they are aware of this issue?

Comment: my "workaround" would be to remove \space from the spec. of the second family of plot markers

Comment: @GregoryRut: I stumbled on this problem when plotting several lines of data on top of each other and was shifting the markers slightly to deal with markers that end up on top of each others.  So this isn't a workaround for me unfortunately.

Comment: @halirutan: I just reported the bug :)

Comment: @kuropan yep, saw it, and it is a duplicate of (or at least heavily related to) other issues around `PlotMarkers`. They have been fixed, and will be available in a future release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** a simpler work-around: add the option `Mesh -> Full`

```
data = {{3, 4, 5}, {1, anything, Infinity, 2}} ;
ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {{"◆", 13}, {"   ◆", 13}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black},
  Mesh -> Full]
```

[image]

Related Q/A: [ListPlot inserts extra PlotMarkers and Mesh at crossing points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63567/125)

**Original answer:**

The issue is not limited to data sets containing `∞`, we get the same issue if `∞` is replaced with any non-numeric element.

A work-around: (1) transform input data to have explicit horizontal coordinates and (1) delete pairs with non-numeric elements:

```
data = {{3, 4, 5}, {1, anything, Infinity, 2}} ;
ListPlot[DeleteCases[Transpose[{Range[Length @ #], #}] & /@ data, 
    {_, Except[_?NumericQ]}, {2}],
  PlotMarkers -> {{"◆", 13}, {"   ◆", 13}},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure that `DataRange` is a general solution for any `Not@*NumericQ` at any place.

Comment: @rhermans, good point. i just updated with an alternative approach which i hope is more general.

Comment: Nice workarounds! Just noticed that you deleted the space in front of the second [\FilledDiamond] though, so you would not actually see from running the code, if your workarounds resolved the issue (as the markers would lay on top of each other).

Comment: @kuropan, i had actually copy-pasted the wrong line; corrected now.