# Possible bug in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting in 11.2**

Possibly the same bug as [(41706)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41706/280).

---

Take a look at the first two points on the chart:

```
ListLinePlot[{15, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: ListLinePlot output]

I have just notified support about this (CASE:3539237), but I wanted to share it with the community.

**Update 2017-08-31**: The bug seems to be back in version 11.1

Comment: That's bizarre!

Comment: I don't think this was fixed in 10.4.  That version simply used a larger automatic PlotRange, but if any part of the line was outside of the plot range, the stray point was still there.

Comment: I also wouldn't call the smaller plot range a bug.  It is reasonable to exclude outliers, and of course it is not very clear what should be considered an outlier ... so Mathematica won't always be able to automatically come up with a plot range that is best for your application.  Sometimes manual corrections are necessary.  (As for the stray point: clearly a bug.)

Comment: The bug is the non-existent point at (1,24). It doesn't happen in 10.4

Comment: [It does happen in 10.4.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UauGb.png)  It only happens when not all data fits in the plot range (and 10.4 seems to have a different automatic plot range determination: in this case it fits all the data).

Comment: I would remove the "fixed" word from the bug header also for another reason: if WRI people search this site for bugs, they may use [scripts that automatically exclude any question whose bug header contains "fixed"](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1610/12).  I am really fed up with this long-standing bug and I want to see it fixed already.

Comment: @Szabolcs Please update the header as you see fit. It originally said fixed in 10.4 but it is definitely still present.

Answer (score 11):

A workaround is to add `ClippingStyle -> False`:

```
ListLinePlot[{15, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35}, Mesh -> All, ClippingStyle -> False]
```

> [image: plot]

I think that this `ListPlot` bug is related:

[Unwanted PlotMarkers appear at non-existent places](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41706/280)

Comment: Alexey, I was about to mark this question as a duplicate of that one; do you have reason to believe this is *not* the same bug?

Comment: I think that this is another manifestation of the same underlying bug. I agree that this question can be considered as a duplicate although this manifestation is different.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Now it is clear that this bug (fixed in version 10.4) is completely independent from [that one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41706/280) (still persists).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It wasn't fixed in 10.4.  10.4 computes the `Automatic` plot range differently, and all the points will fit within it. If you manually set the same plot range that other versions use, [the problem is there](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UauGb.png). I put in the PlotRangePadding only for better visibility.  I also think it's the same bug as in the other question (but it looks different enough to keep a separate question).

Answer (score 4):

The problem does not occur if the `PlotRange` is specified

```
ListLinePlot[{15, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35}, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[{15, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35}, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {14, 36}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly true : see what happens with `PlotRange->{20,36}` : the two extra first markers are there (even if they are hard to see). Interestingly, if you add the option `PlotMarkers -> {Automatic,20}` the first extra marker disappears, the second is still there. Interestingly again, if you set `Mesh -> Full` then the second extra marker disappears, the first is back !

Comment: @SquareOne - Yes, solution provided by [Alexey Popov](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) appears more robust.