# How can one control the style of the cut off markers on a plot?

Tags: plotting, bugs

I am well aware I could simply increase the PlotRange to fix this, however, I'd like to keep the scale identical to some plots I compare this with. Also I haven't found anything about this and it only happens when I put a frame around my plots.

Initially I thought the outlying observation is styled just like the respective line, but that is not the case it seems.

*plots were created with Mathematica 11*

**edit:**

PlotRangeClipping False/True only allows to display the full circle (as in the image) or clip it, but there do not seem to be any options to actually style (change color or shape of the marker) or remove any indication of clipping.

**edit2:**

So here's an example with some simple code. Notice the blue indication where the lines leave the plot. I'd like to change the appearance of these.

```
 ListLinePlot[{{70, 25, 20, 15, 11}, {38, 15, 12, 8, 2}}, 
 ImageSize -> 450, PlotRange -> {{0.85, 5.15}, {0, 35}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledCircle], 15}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: To be more precise, i was wondering if one could control the "clipping" indication, to have anything else than a red circle. And thank you for your answer, i'll try finding more information on Clipping.

Comment: I fear that might be a bug and not a clipping indicator ...

Comment: Since a moderator closed this question so quickly, I can't post this as a answer, but there is a work-around. if you assign your plot to a variable, say `plot`, then ``DeleteCases[plt, {{_, 35.`}}, ∞]`` will give a plot without the bogus markers.

Comment: This does the same in my case as what Szabolcs noted (ClippingStyle->False). See also here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41708/42848

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry to have to say this, but that is not a clipping indicator.  It is a bug in `ListPlot`.  Here's a simple way to reproduce it:

```
ListPlot[{{4, 3, 2, 1, 0}, {10, 5, 4, 2, 1}}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, PlotRange -> {0, 6}]
```

[image]

Notice that where the second (yellow) line is clipped, a plot marker of *the first line* has appeared.  This might have been discussed on this site before, <del>but I'm lazy to search for it (anyone else?).</del> **Update:** [Here's a mention.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41706/12)  Workaround is `ClippingStyle -> False`, which makes it go away.

Please do report this misbehaviour to [Wolfram Support](http://support.wolfram.com/).  If more people report it, there's a higher chance that it'll get fixed.